# Missing header files for tidy html for c

Tags: c++, html-parsing, codeblocks, htmltidy

I want to create a project using **c++** using **html tidy** to get an xml file.([Almost this](http://www.mostthingsweb.com/2013/02/parsing-html-with-c/))

But I have basic knowledge of c++ programming and haven't ever worked with other APIs and libraries.
In the example above the program includes *tidy.h* and *buffio.h*, which i don't know where to find and how to use.(I downloaded the zip of html tidy from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tidy/),but it doesn't contain any of the above said files.)
So where can I find these and how to use them with Code Blocks on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see both of those files in the Tidy source code:

http://tidy.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tidy/tidy/include

I don't see any zip files, so I'm not sure what it is you've downloaded, but try downloading the tarball here:

http://tidy.cvs.sourceforge.net/tidy/

To use them, simply make sure the folder containing the files is in your compiler's include paths, and then `#include` them as the sample code you linked to does. Don't forget to link to any compiled code which you need as well. The following tutorial may help you do that in Code Blocks:

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/

Comment: Thanks alot. By the way what's the use of the tarball?

Comment: @DeepanshuSharma It's a similar concept to a `zip` file - a way to combine multiple files into one file with (optional) compression. `zip` is more common on Windows, and `tar` is more common on *nix. Most general purpose compression utilities such as 7-Zip can handle both formats (and others).